# $\sqrt{9x^2-16}>3x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

I'm trying to solve the following inequality:

> $$\sqrt{9x^2-16}>3x+1$$

---

Here's my attempt:

$\sqrt{9x^2-16}>3x+1$
$\longrightarrow 9x^2-16>9x^2+6x+1$
$\longrightarrow -16>6x+1$
$\longrightarrow x<-\frac{17}{6}$

Now, I need to check the constraints:

$9x^2-16 > 0$
$\longrightarrow (3x)^2 > 4^2$
$\longrightarrow \pm3x > 4$
$\longrightarrow 3x > 4$; $-3x > 4$
$\longrightarrow x > \frac{4}{3}$; $x < -\frac{4}{3}$

Making sure the answer meets the constraints:
$\{(-\infty, -\frac{4}{3})\cup(\frac{4}{3}, \infty)\}\cap (-\infty, -\frac{17}{6}) = (-\infty, -\frac{17}{6})$

So, my answer is $x=(-\infty, -\frac{17}{6})$, however verifying on Wolfram|Alpha results in $x=(-\infty, -\frac{4}{3}]$.

---

**Where, what, and why is wrong with my solution?**

Comment: Your first move was to square both sides.  Note that $2 > -3$ but $4<9$.

Comment: First of all one should have $9x^2-16\geqslant 0$, not $>0$.

Comment: @B.Goddard -- Oh, right. Thank you; I'll see what your correction results in. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack -- Good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the domain of the inequation is $(-\infty,-4/3]\cup[4/3,+\infty)$.

Next, you should know that, when $A\ge 0$,
$$\sqrt A>B\iff A >B^2\quad\text{or}\quad B<0.$$
In the present case, one gets
\begin{cases}
9x^2-16>(3x+1)^2\iff x<-\dfrac{17}6 \\
\quad \text{or}\\
x<-\dfrac13.
\end{cases}
Both conditions yield $x\in (-\infty,-1/3)$. Taking the domain of validity of the inequation into account, one obtains
$$x\le-\frac43.$$

Answer (score 1):

1. $3x+1\leq0$ and $9x^2-16\geq0$, which gives $x\leq-\frac{4}{3}$;
2. $3x+1>0$ and $9x^2-16>(3x+1)^2$. The last gives $x<-\frac{17}{6}$, which is impossible.

Thus, the answer is $\left(-\infty,-\frac{4}{3}\right]$.

Answer (score 0):

at first it must be $|x|\geq \frac{4}{3}$ if $$x\le -\frac{1}{3}$$ our inequality is true. let $$x>-\frac{1}{3}$$ we can square it:
$$9x^2-16>9x^2+6x+1$$ otr $$x<-\frac{17}{6}$$ together with the conditions $$-\infty<x<-\frac{17}{6}$$ and $$-\frac{1}{3}<x$$ or $$-\frac{1}{3}\geq x$$ and $$x\geq \frac{4}{3}$$ or $$x\le -\frac{4}{3}$$ we get $$-\infty<x\le- \frac{4}{3}$$ as the searched solution set

Answer (score 0):

$a > b \implies a^2 > b$ is not true if $b < 0$.

We have two cases:

1) if $3x + 1 \ge 0$ or $x \ge -\frac 13$ you correctly got $x < \frac {-17}6$.  But that contradicts $x \ge -\frac 13$

So we must have case 2:

2)  $3x + 1 < 0$ and $x < -\frac 13$.

From that we *can't* square both sides as $a \ge 0 > b$ does/can not tell us anything about $a^2$ in relation to $b^2$ as $|a|$ and $|b|$ can be *any* relation.

In other words we have no idea if $\sqrt{x^2 - 16}^2 >,<, = (3x + 1)^2$.  Any one of those is possible.

But we *do* have $9x^2 - 16 \ge 0$ and $x < -1/3$.  That will get you $x^2 \ge \frac {16}9$ so $|x| \ge \frac 43$ so either $x \ge \frac 43$ which is is a contradiction, or $x \le -\frac 43$.  So $x \le -\frac 43$

So we have $x \le -\frac 43$ and $x < -\frac 13$.  So solution is $x \le -\frac 43$.